# How to get drive file name using URL using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Does anyone know hot to get the name of a file on drive using an URL?

At the moment I have the below code but it just hangs for some reason :(.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobID = 262;
  var jobFormUrl = 'URL';
  var jobFormId = getIdFromUrl(jobFormUrl);
  var filename = DriveApp.getFileById(jobFormId).getName();

  ss.getSheetByName('Job ID '+jobID).getRange(2,2).setValue('=hyperlink("'+jobFormUrl+'","'+filename+'")');
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) {
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
}
```

Comment: "[...] but it doesn't work"? Try to describe what is not working exactly.

Comment: @fuma Sorry about that. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getIdFromUrl() function is returning an array whereas it should return a string representing the ID of the file.

```
function getIdFromUrl(url) {
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the quotes from line 8 to the variable definition fixes this. So instead of `var jobFormUrl = 'URL';` it should be `var jobFormUrl = '"URL"';`